# How to create OLAP cube from multiple stores in databrewery cubes

Tags: python, olap, cubes

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around OLAP cubes.

For learning, I am using the [cubes](http://cubes.databrewery.org/) framework.

I'm currently stuck at making a cube that depends on dimensions from two different stores.

I've tried to use the fact that all defined dimensions are public by default to achieve this.

Below is some anonymized code showing how I'm trying to solve it:

```
workspace = Workspace()
workspace.register_store("store1", "sql", schema="schema1", url="postgresql://<URL>")
workspace.register_store("store2", "sql", schema="schema2", url="postgresql://<URL>")
workspace.import_model("model1.json", store="store1")
workspace.import_model("model2.json", store="store2")
workspace.import_model("cube_with_dimensions_from_model1_and_model2.json")
browser = workspace.browser("cube_with_dimensions_from_model1_and_model2")
```

I get the error

> cubes.errors.NoSuchDimensionError: Dimension 'dimesion_from_model2'
>   not found

This obviously means that it can't find the dimensions imported in model1 and model2.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to solve this?

**PS:** If there are more sample projects than those found [here](https://github.com/Stiivi/cubes-examples) I would be very grateful to know.

Comment: Can you share your example models as a gist or pastebin, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cubes currently creates a separate namespace for each store, if not specified otherwise. In your example, every model ends up in the namespace of the store (that is `store1` and `store2`). Default (global) namespace remains empty, therefore the Workspace can't find your dimension in another store.

Try one of the following options:

### A. use default namespace

```
workspace.import_model("model1.json", "store1", namespace="default")
workspace.import_model("model2.json", "store2", namespace="default")
```

### B. Separate common dimensions

Put shared dimensions into `model_common.json` (or rather `common.cubesmodel` [directory](http://cubes.databrewery.org/dev/doc/model.html#file-representation)) and import it separately without any store or namespace specified (the dimensions will end-up in the default/global namespace):

```
workspace.import_model("common.cubesmodel")
workspace.import_model("model1.json", "store1")
workspace.import_model("model2.json", "store2")
```

Comment: I haven't gotten the chance to try it out yet, but I'm pretty sure this is it. I just assumed everything was put into the global namespace unless specified otherwise. Guess I missed that part of the docs ;)

Comment: Ok, after trying out some more, I couldn't get it to work. The cube would automatically end up in its own namespace for the purpose of searching for other model providers. I fixed this by prefixing the cube name with a namespace. Like "default.cubename". This caused the correct model providers to be searched. Problem was though, that line 653 in workspace.py says cube = ns.cube(ns_cube, locale=locale, recursive=recursive) instead of cube = ns.cube(name, locale=locale, recursive=recursive). Which means the lookup for cubes fail when you give them a namespace. It worked after changing that line.

Comment: Now I came as far as getting "sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError: organizations" when looking up a table that the cube used. The reason is simple: The organizations table does not exist in both of the stores I have provided. It only exists in store2, which uses schema2. I'm uncertain how this is supposed to work with multiple stores pr. cube.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am using approach A, putting everything in a "default" namespace

Comment: To elaborate why I had to hack workspace.py: the namespace_for_cube function returns a namespace containing only one model provider if I do not specify my cube name like this "default.cubename" and then call result = workspace.browser("default.cubename")

Comment: Oh, of course it's looking for the organizations table in the wrong store. I had set up the wrong store when importing the cube. The problem is though, that the cube needs two different stores. If I don't set a store when I import the cube I get the following error message: cubes.errors.ConfigurationError: No info for store default